# Window.history.state is null after form submission takes user to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I call `thiswindow.history.pushState(this.state,'','/Customer_Info/');`

When I check on developer tools on the current page, state is defined, but on `customerInfo` page state is null.

I arrive on `customerInfo` page from a form submission.

I am assuming that the history.state should be in scope on the second page. Am I correct? Perhaps my URL string is incorrect? ( I am using React with Gatsby) Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think your assumption is correct. However, it might be worth using gatsby's navigate helper to do this https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function

Comment: I actually was originally using Gatsby's navigate helper but I want to switched to a " submit" button for better form controls

Comment: I don't think this impacts your ability to navigate on a form submit event.